# Half duplex UDP?

Tags: udp, ethernet

I’ve developed an application which communicates with an external piece of equipment via UDP. In most cases it seems to work perfectly, but I have one customer who has experienced packet loss when using my application on one particular laptop. His other laptop is fine.

He checked the obvious things like buffer sizes, but there’s nothing obviously wrong.

He then installed EtherSnoop on the laptop to try to see what is going on, and it would appear that whenever the laptop transmits a message to the external equipment, it stops listening to incoming messages for a short time. It’s as if the laptop’s Ethernet link is only capable of half duplex operation.

The laptop concerned is an HP using a RealTek network chip. His good laptop is a Lenovo using an Intel network chip.

Are there any other settings that could cause this behavior? The packet loss is not acceptable in this application, and we need to find out what is "different" about the HP.

Comment: You might want to edit in a question. Are you looking for verification that half-duplex is a thing? Are you looking for methods to detect this and mitigate packet loss?

Comment: Note: even a (working) half-duplex nic will not drop packets. It will be queued until the channel is free. Unless the queue is full, ofc.

Comment: I've just amended the question.

Comment: If packet loss is not acceptable, UDP may be a bad choice. TCP would retransmit until the receiver has acknowledged.

Comment: I agree that UDP is a poor choice, but that is what the manufacturer of the equipment concerned chose, so that is what I have to use. I suspect they chose UDP as it is faster than TCP, and this is a real time system.

Comment: UDP is only "faster" than TCP on an unreliable connection - UDP loses dropped packets, TCP retransmits, delaying later packets.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if the client system runs unreliably / experiences packet loss, there's little you can do. UDP should get reliably (see below) delivered even when a half-duplex link is used as per CSMA/CD - unless there's a duplex mismatch or the collision domain is too large.

You could troubleshoot the network connection, rule out / fix a duplex mismatch, check cables, check NIC & switch configs, update NIC driver, replace hardware - USB dongle?, ...

A duplex mismatch can be caused by either the switch port or the NIC. Unless configured badly it's very rare though. You will see FCS errors on the full-duplex side and extreme collision counts on the half-duplex side. Overall, the connection will behave very slow when you try to seriously use it. Gigabit links use FDX only, so a duplex mismatch will be extremely unlikely.

PS: as EJP has correctly pointed out, UDP cannot be "reliable" as in engineering, 100.0%-reliable - above, I am using the garden-variety of "reliable" as in 99%-or-so.

Comment: There is nothing reliable about UDP. It is a fire-and-forget protocol.

Comment: UDP relies 100% on the underlying protocol for delivery. Running across an Ethernet network, it _should_ get through unless the network has issues.

Answer (score -1):

This problem turned out to be caused by buffer overrun on the laptop concerned. As to why this particular laptop is different to the others is still a mystery. I have since modified my app to account for the buffer issue on this particular laptop, and all now seems to be well.